# generate multiple txt files from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize for what may be a naive question, but is there a way using a mySQL script to generate multiple text files from the contents of a table? For example, given the following table:

**Table: basket**

> ```
> id_basket     id_client    item
> 1             1            apple  
> 2             1            mushroom
> 3             4            potato
> 4             4            cherry
> 5             4            apple   
> 6             7            sausage
> ...etc.
> ```

to generate \n delimited txt files as follows:

**1.txt**

```
 apple
 mushroom
```

**4.txt**

```
 potato
 cherry
 apple
```

**7.txt**

```
 sausage
```

...etc.

Ideally I'd like to do this without resorting to php, but I accept that php may be the only easy route. I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions!

James

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Run your select, order by `id_client`, loop the return and create/append files based on `id_client`.

Comment: Thanks Chris85, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.this is working

**Note : first you create a file directory under your root folder.**

```
$res  = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item) AS items , id_client FROM basket GROUP BY id_client");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $fileName = $row['id_client'].".txt";
    $csv = str_replace(",",PHP_EOL,$row['items']);
    $csv_handler = fopen ("files/".$fileName,'w');
    fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
    fclose ($csv_handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM basket");
while($assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$filesname = $assoc['id_client'].'.txt';
$contents = $assoc['item']."\n";
$put = file_put_contents($filesname, $contents, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Try this :) its will work :).